# how to Save File using C# Windows Application

Tags: c#

I'm using C# windows application .
  I want to save files in my local system.
I used Open File dialog to attach the files.
Here the text inside the file is copying,I want the file itself to get copied with a new name.But what I am really looking for is , it should just save the file automatically and not show the SaveDialog Box?
How it can be done in windows application.Can anybody help me please?
The code is shown below:

```
private string GetFileName()
        {
            OpenFileDialog op1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            DialogResult result = op1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                txtEn.Text = op1.FileName;
                FileName = op1.FileName;
                //MessageBox.Show(FileName);
                File.Copy(op1.FileName, @"D:\Backup\");

            }
            return FileName;

        }
```

Comment: The workstation would need to have access to the server's file system, which is entirely outside the scope of the application.  If the server has a file share, use that.  If it doesn't, then you can't write to its file system.

Comment: You would need to make the c: drive on the server shared or upload the file using ftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 seems unrelated to your question. Provided that you have proper access rights to the target directory, then in order to automate the procedure (as per your question) you don't need to use the `OpenFileDialog`; just a single line should suffice the goal:

```
//Overwriting a file of the same name is not allowed
File.Copy(FileName, @"D:\Backup\" + FileName)
```

or

```
//Overwriting a file of the same name is allowed
File.Copy(FileName, @"D:\Backup\" + FileName, true)
```

You can also apply some additional logic pertinent to backup file naming (upon necessity).

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to copy a file from some x location on your file system to y location (in your case D:\Backup folder) in the file system? If that is the requirement here, I see that you are using the FileName property of OpenFileDialog which gets the File path. This you are appending to D:\Backup. You should instead use the Path.GetFileName property to first extract the file name with extension and then append it to the new folder path

```
File.Copy(fileName, @"D:\Backup\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

Comment: I want to save the file in my local system,automatically without using save file dialog.I searched google,but i'm not finding anything.